# No Access-Allow-Origin header is present on the requested resource

Tags: jquery, ajax, angular, post

When I post data through Angular 2, I'm getting this error in Chrome as well as Mozilla. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Welcome to _StackOverflow_! Here, you can learn [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) properly before you do so. When asking a question, be sure you are [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and always try to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when possible.

Comment: This scenario occurs when One server request to fetch data from another server. So you should add Allow-Origin header in response

Comment: Agree, but what if it not work , when i already added the Allow Origin Header in my php file?

Answer (score -1):

A simple answer is that we need to add a Chrome or Mozilla extension to avoid this kind of error when posting data through jQuery AJAX or Angular 2 application using typescript.

We need to just copy the question and paste in google.com and include 'Extension for Chrome' or Mozilla.

Comment: `A simple answer is , we need to add a chrome or mozila extension to avoid this kind of error`. That's a really bad solution. It relies on your users downloading a browser extension to be able to use your site correctly. No one is going to do that. A much better solution would be to either send your server response with the correct headers for cross-domain requests, or make the request server side.

Comment: I'd also suggest you delete this question as it has been asked and answered much more effectively literally thousands of times before.

Comment: But what if i have already added header(""Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*") in my php file, since the error is same.

Comment: Then you most likely have another error in the console which you should investigate. If it's a site you control, check you've also set the correct `Access-Control-Allow-Headers`. If it's not your site, then there's nothing you can do except send the request server side. As I mentioned, using an extension means that every person who browses your site needs to use that extension - not just you, hence why it is not a workable fix.

Comment: I answer , like this because the same code is working in another computer, with perfect response, but not working on my computer,

Comment: Exactly my point.

Comment: My point too, but when i installed the extention cros, it was started working

Comment: Right - it works *for you but no one else who visits your site*

Comment: That's why i suggest this answer because it may be the problem of current chrome.

Comment: One more thing i want to add is, this problem is only happening when i work in local machine , once it live, there is no issue.

Comment: we can also follow this link for more clarification ::  ,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: I know - that's the question I already marked as a duplicate :)

Comment: But the answer was not clear there.

Comment: You literally just said in your previous comment that the link gave more clarification...? I think I'm done. I still suggest you delete this question. Best of luck.